# Find If a node exists in all maximum bipartite matchings

Tags: algorithms, bipartite-matching

Given a bipartite graph, I need to find for **each** node, If this node exists in all the possible maximum matchings of the given graph or not.

Note that there can be multiple maximum matchings  of a given bipartite graph with the same value of matching but different set of edges.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: For a given node, you can remove the node and see whether this reduces the size of a maximum matching. There might be something more efficient in your case, though.

Comment: I can tell you how to efficiently list all *edges* that are present in every maximum matching.  I don't know how to efficiently list all *vertices* that are present in every maximum matching, though.  Is that useful?  If so, I can show the detailed explanation in an answer.  It uses http://stackoverflow.com/q/41964288/781723 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/29418244/781723.  (I'm hesitant to clutter up this page with an 'answer' that doesn't answer your question, for fear of causing the question to be treated as 'answered' when it really isn't.)